# PHP retrieve information from array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need pick up values from array.

My code:

```
$tags = $array['bePVM'][''];
echo ('<form action="" method="POST">');
for($o = 0; $o<$i; $o++){
   echo "<br>Užsakymo: <b> ",$data2DArray[$o][0], "</b> Price witout VAT: ",'<input type="text" name="bePVM[]" value="">'," VAT: ",'<input type="text" name="PVM[]" value="">'," Price with VAT: ",'<input type="text" name="suPVM[]" value="">',"<br>";
}
echo ('<input type="submit" value="">');
echo ('</form>');
print_r($_POST);
    echo $tags[1];
```

And i have this output:

```
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null


Array ( [bePVM] => Array ( [0] => 100 
                           [1] => 200 ) 
          [PVM] => Array ( [0] => 21 
                           [1] => 42  ) 
        [suPVM] => Array ( [0] => 121 
                           [1] => 242 ) 
      )
```

How can i echo [bePVM][1] where is 200?

thanks

Comment: you've declared tag `$tags = $array['bePVM'][''];` and you are printing `echo $tags[1];` which will show `array offset on value of type null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i echo [bePVM][1] where is 200?

If the output is from `print_r($_POST);` then this should write `200` to the output:

```php
echo $_POST['bePVM'][1];
```